# R: Extract first two digits from nested list elements

Tags: r, substring, strsplit

For the following vector, I would to keep only the first two digits of each integer:

```
a <- c('1234 2345 345 234', '323 55432 443', '43 23345 321')
```

I've attempted to do this by converting the vector into a nested list using `strsplit` and then applying `substr` to the list:

```
a <- strsplit(a, ' ')
a <- substr(a, start = 1, stop = 2)
```

However, this seems to just extract eh beginning of the concatenated command:

```
a
[1] "c(" "c(" "c("
```

Ideally, I would be able to coerce the vector into the following form:

```
[[1]]
[1] "12" "23" "34" "23"

[[2]]
[1] "32" "55" "44"

[[3]]
[1] "43" "23" "32"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
lapply(strsplit(a, " "), substr, 1, 2)
```

this explicitly does an `lapply` over the results of the `strsplit`. This is because `substr()` tries to coerce your list to a character vector first (it doesn't expect a list as it's first parameter). You can see what it's looking at if you do

```
as.character(strsplit(a, ' '))
# [1] "c(\"1234\", \"2345\", \"345\", \"234\")" "c(\"323\", \"55432\", \"443\")"         
# [3] "c(\"43\", \"23345\", \"321\")"
```

Comment: That worked fantastically - thank you! Also, thanks for taking the time to explain how I was misunderstanding `substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also extract the first two digits from a word boundary

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(a, "\\b\\d{2}")
#[[1]]
#[1] "12" "23" "34" "23"

#[[2]]
#[1] "32" "55" "44"

#[[3]]
#[1] "43" "23" "32"
```